# Why isn't the scope variable defined in the directive showing in the view or controller?

Tags: angularjs, directive

I'm fetching data using a directive and creating a scope variable 'services', but it doesn't show up in the view and in the controller it is 'undefined.'  What's the best way to have the data show?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('myTag', ['$http', function($http, $scope) {

    //http://apidocs.bookingbug.com/public.html#!/company/get_company_company_id
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,     
    scope:{
        src:"="       
    },
    controller:function($scope, $attrs){
        console.info("enter directive controller");

        $http({
            method: 'GET', 
            url:$scope.src,
            headers: {
                'App-Id': '5a3d8b8d',
                'App-Key': '738e9aca62e7465446b7be8fe4219ffa'
            }
        }).then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);                              
            console.log(result.data._embedded.services);                              

            var states = result.data._embedded.services;
            var services = []; 
            angular.forEach(states, function (state) {
                var service = {
                    'description':state.description,
                    'name':state.name,
                    'prices':state.prices[0]
                }

                services.push(service)
            });     
            $scope.services = services; 

            console.log($scope);
            console.log($scope.services); //This shows correctly - array of objects. 

        }, function (result) {
            alert("Error: No data returned");
        });
    }
    }
}]).controller('MainController', function ($scope) {        
            console.log($scope.services); //This shows undefined

});
```

html:

```
  <ul class="the-results">
    <li ng-repeat="service in services">
      <a href="#" id="{{ $index + 1 }}">{{ service.name }}</a>, {{ service.description }}
    </li>
  </ul>

<my-tag src="'https://uk.bookingbug.com/api/v1/41285/services'"></my-tag>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this in your directive ?

```
$scope.$parent.services = services;
```

And then in your controller:

```
console.log($scope.services);
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: you're awesome.  Sorry I'm new to angular.  So a directive is a child of a controller?  Can u explain it a little for the green mark?

Comment: Yes, a directive is exactly a child of a controller.
So you can access to each $scope.controllerVars by $scope.$parent.controllerVars in your directives

Comment: Just for the record, the  `console.log($scope.services);`  still shows first and undefined even though the view is populated.  If I wanted to run some functionality in the controller for instance `$scope.services.description = $scope.services.description.toUpperCase()` I'd still run into an error.